# Heritage, child variable not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This problem is on Unity, but I think I am just doing the c# side wrong.

**EDIT**

**It looks like by doing the code and storing a child Class B of parent Class A, and by saying is a Class A type, by modifing my variable of type Class A containing Class B I modify some sort of hybrid Class A/B that doesn't represent my real Class B Script**

What I do is, having multiple script on different prefabs. Each of those script represent an item and all have has parent Usable which is a class that I actually use like an interface, but that will in the future get some stuff.

The full `WeaponLaser` and `Usable` script is below

When the player go over a drop, I instantiate the gameObject containing the script like this (using prefab)

```
GameObject Item = Instantiate(droppedItem, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
Item.transform.parent = transform;
usableItem = droppedItem.GetComponent<Usable>();
usableItem.OnUsed += ReleaseItem;
```

and Use the item like this

```
if (usableItem != null)
    usableItem.Use(firePoint.position);
```

The thing is, it looks like the script I call when I do Use() is another version.

I mean, If I set     `int fireCurrentShoot = 10;` on top of the script WeaponLaser and then trought code in the Start for exemple I do         `fireCurrentShoot = 2;`

It will work on the inside the script WeaponLaser, but when I call it using the above code

```
    if (usableItem != null)
    usableItem.Use(firePoint.position);
```

It will show `fireCurrentShoot = 10` so without the modification

**END EDIT**

Hello,

I have a problem with heritage I don't understand, I cleaned all my class, and still I can't find why.

I have a class A :

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class Usable : MonoBehaviour
 {
     protected virtual void Start()
     {
     }

     protected virtual void Update()
     {
     }

     public virtual void Use(Vector3 pos)
     {
     }

     protected virtual void Used()
     {
     }
 }
```

and a class B

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class WeaponLaser : Usable
 {
     const int SHOOT_AVAILABLE = 5;
     const float FIRE_COOLDOWN = 1;
     float fireCurrentCooldown = 0.0f;
     int fireCurrentShoot = 0;

     protected override void Start()
     {
        base.Start();
        Debug.Log("start");
        fireCurrentShoot = SHOOT_AVAILABLE;
        Debug.Log("fireCurrentShoot" + fireCurrentShoot);
     }

     protected override void Update()
     {
         Debug.Log(fireCurrentShoot); // value is = 5
         base.Update();
     }

     public override void Use(Vector3 shootPosition)
     {
         Debug.Log(fireCurrentShoot);// value is = 0
         base.Use(shootPosition);
         base.Used();
     }

     void FireCooldown()
     {

     }
 }
```

when I call Use, my Debug.Log of booth value give 0... but I am expecting to have `fireCurrentShoot = 5`

I call it like this *:

```
    usableItem = droppedItem.GetComponent<Usable>();
usableItem.Use(firePoint.position);
```

why he is equal to 0?

Comment: I doubt that the problem is because of inheritance. It seems that you overwrite the value at some point, or that you are left with the initial value. When do you use `Start` ? I cannot see why you expect to have a value of `5`. the initial value is `0` why should it be `5` ?

Comment: You are not calling `Start` - so the value of `fireCurrentShoot` is not updated to 5.

Comment: In Unity, Start is called by default by the engine, so it is called, the debug do show the value @MongZhu

Comment: My guess is that something's creating another instance then. Add an explicit parameterless constructor and put some logging in there.

Comment: How is it possible that debug.log in the start methods gives 5, when you call it BEFORE setting the value? Did you mix two lines in your example?

Comment: @Toaster good point, is because I edit the code on stack a bit, it is after in mine, Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inheritance seems fine, so the problem might be in the way you use these objects in Unity. This makes it a bit more difficult to be sure what the solution is, but here is what you could try:

- Be sure that Start is called: I think it is the case for you since
  you say you see a debug print, but remember that Start is not called
  on objects that are deactivated in the Editor, so some values that
  you set in start will not be initialized.
- Name your objects in unity editor with unique names and add the name in the debug

  ```
  Debug.Log(fireCurrentShoot + ", " + name);
  ```

  This should help you sure you see the values for the object that interests you
- You can also replace

  ```
  int fireCurrentShoot = 0;
  ```

  by a property:

  ```
  int _fireCurrentShoot = 0;
  private int fireCurrentShoot
  {
      get{ return _fireCurrentShoot;}
      set{ _fireCurrentShoot = value; Debug.log("fireCurrentShot set to " + _fireCurrentShoot);}
  }
  ```

  this will allow you to see a message when the value is modified. You 
  can also set a debug point on the setter to see the callstack

**EDIT:**

I think I got it: you don't register to the instanciated object, but to your prefab

replace

```
usableItem = droppedItem.GetComponent<Usable>();
```

by

```
usableItem = Item.GetComponent<Usable>();
```

Comment: Hello, I didn't thougt about the property thing, in fact it helped me.

I think my fail stand in what I do with object in unity. I will Edit my main question with what I found

Comment: I saw your edit, but are you sure about what you wrote? you say that in 
 Start you set fireCurrentShoot = 2 and later you see that the value is 2... So that seems the wanted behaviour

Comment: Yes Sorry again... I am so bad I getting help cause I'm unclear and make mistake while I ask help --

Basically yes, the value of the base script is the one I catch from outside the code (so when I call Use) and the value that I modify inside the script is the one I get from inside.

I would like them to be the same.

But I do understand that is quite a mess to understand or to find the solution like this, So I guess I will find some other way to do

Comment: Don't be sorry, you still provided way more useful info than many people here. That being said, I edited my answer with a last thing I noticed that might solve it. Good luck

Comment: OMGOMG It was that the all time, i was about to redo all cause I knew it was some little mistake I will never find xD

Nice eyes man, thank you verrryyy much for that !